# Per Page Permalink Structure for Page Post Type

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

I am trying to Re-Write Page URL's so that they END with `.htm`

I was able to do this using...

```
/* Add .htm extension to Page URL Links */
add_action('init', 'htm_page_permalink', -1);
function htm_page_permalink() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if ( !strpos($wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct(), '.htm')){
        $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->page_structure . '.htm';
    }
}

/* Remove the trailing slash/ on Pages */
add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'no_page_slash',66,2);
function no_page_slash($string, $type){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() && $wp_rewrite->use_trailing_slashes==true && $type == 'page'){
        return untrailingslashit($string);
    }else{
        return $string;
    }
}
```

But then I ran into a problem where I am using my `Blog` post list on a Page named `Blog`.  I need this page to **NOT** end with `.htm`

So I then used this code to change the Page Links to filter out the `.htm` on my `blog` page...

```
/* Filter .htm out of Blog Page Links */
function blog_page_url($content) {
    $current_path = '/blog.htm';
    $new_path = '/blog/';
    $content = str_replace($current_path, $new_path, $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter('_get_page_link', 'blog_page_url');
```

And I used this Re-write rule to make `/blog/` load the `Blog Page` ...

```
/* Setup Custom Re-write for the Blog Page */
add_action( 'init', 'blog_page_rewrite' );
function blog_page_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule('blog', 'index.php?pagename=blog','top' );
    //add_rewrite_rule('blog/(.*?)/', 'index.php?p=$matches[1]','top' );
}
```

But now I have the problme that any URL with the `/blog/` in it is showing the `Blog page`.

This means my actual blog post which are set up in WP Permalink settings like this...

`/blog/%postname%/` are not working, instead they always show the `Blog page` which list all the blog posts.

In my `blog_page_rewrite()` function above you can see I had tested an extra re-write rule to hopefully work with the Blog posts but it had no affect.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Blog page the one that's set in the back end at `Settings > Reading > Posts page`?  If so, try checking for that in your first function:

```
/* Add .htm extension to Page URL Links */
add_action('init', 'htm_page_permalink', -1);
function htm_page_permalink() {
    global $post;
    if( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) == $post->ID ) {
         // don't add .htm to this page
         return;
    }
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if ( !strpos($wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct(), '.htm')){
        $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->page_structure . '.htm';
    }
}
```

The [Option Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference) pointed me at `page_for_posts`.

Comment: I actually just got it all working with my current solution by changing my `add_rewrite_rule` paramters from `top` to `bottom` but I will also investigate what you have here and see how it works as well, thanks

Comment: Just letting you know it doesn't work, I appreciate the attempt and in theory it really looks like it should work

Comment: That's strange.  Oh well, you got it working another way...